# Putting together CSV Cells in Excel with a macro

Tags: vba, csv, excel, vbscript

So, I have a macro to export data into CSV format and it's working great (Code at the bottom).  The problem is the data I am putting into it.  When I put the data in question in it comes out

> Firstname,Lastname,username,password,description

I'd like to change it so I get

> Firstname Lastname,Firstname,Lastname,username,password,description

What I'd like to do is manipulate the existing macro so to accomplish this.  I'm not so good at VBS so any input or a shove in the right direction would be fantastic.

Thanks!

The code is from user Chance2 http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/679620-set-up-macro-to-export-as-csv-file.html.  Fair is fair and the author should be rightly attributed.  I apologize for making any of this sound proprietary.

```
Sub Make_CSV()
Dim sFile As String
Dim sPath As String
Dim sLine As String

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer

    r = 1 'Starting row of data

    sPath = "C:\CSVout\"
    sFile = "MyText_" & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS") & ".CSV"

    Close #1
    Open sPath & sFile For Output As #1
    Do Until IsEmpty(Range("A" & r))
    'You can also Do Until r = 17 (get the first 16 cells)
        sLine = ""
        c = 1
        Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(1, c))
           'Number of Columns - You could use a FOR / NEXT loop instead
            sLine = sLine & """" & Replace(Cells(r, c), ";", ":") & """" & ","
            c = c + 1
        Loop
        Print #1, Left(sLine, Len(sLine) - 1) 'Remove the trailing comma
        r = r + 1
    Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: "Your" macro is listed here http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/679620-set-up-macro-to-export-as-csv-file.html. Please give attributions in your Post

Comment: Done.  I didn't mean for anything to sound proprietary or like I had written it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest change would be to assign `sLine` with the 'Firstname Lastname' concatenation i.e.:

```
Do Until IsEmpty(Range("A" & r))
'You can also Do Until r = 17 (get the first 16 cells)
    sLine = """" & Replace(Cells(r,1) & " " & Cells(r,2), ";", ":") + ""","
    c = 1
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(1, c))
       'Number of Columns - You could use a FOR / NEXT loop instead
        sLine = sLine & """" & Replace(Cells(r, c), ";", ":") & """" & ","
        c = c + 1
    Loop
    Print #1, Left(sLine, Len(sLine) - 1) 'Remove the trailing comma
    r = r + 1
Loop
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you so much El Ronnoco!  I'd vote it up if I had more reputation!